# Replace strings in list from dictionary

Tags: python

I'm having some issues with my code:

```
word_list = { "hello" : "1", "bye" : "2"}

sentence= ['hello you, hows things', 'hello, good thanks']

for key, value in word_list.iteritems():
   for i in sentence:
       i = i.replace(key, value)
print i
```

Expected output = `'1 you, how's things'`, `'1, good thanks'`

It currently does not replace any occurrences of `hello`.  I'm wondering if my sentence loop is correct or not?  Printing `i` after this prints out exactly what is in `sentence`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the `word_list`(try to rename the variable to `word_dict`, I think that is more appropriate) has lots of items,

```
for index, data in enumerate(sentence):
    for key, value in word_list.iteritems():
        if key in data:
            sentence[index]=data.replace(key, word_list[key])
```

working example from `ipython`

```
In [1]: word_list = { "hello" : "1", "bye" : "2"}

In [2]: sentence = ['hello you, hows things', 'hello, good thanks']

In [3]: for index, data in enumerate(sentence):
   ...:         for key, value in word_list.iteritems():
   ...:                 if key in data:
   ...:                         sentence[index]=data.replace(key, word_list[key])
   ...:             

In [4]: sentence
Out[4]: ['1 you, hows things', '1, good thanks']
```

Comment: Python 3 renamed `dict.iteritems() -> dict.items()`!

Answer (score 1):

The replacement occurs on a variable inside the loop
So nothing is changed in the `sentence` list
To fix this make a new list with the changed items in it

```
word_list = { "hello" : "1"}

sentence= ['hello you, hows things', 'hello, good thanks']
newlist=[]

for key, value in word_list.items():
   for i in sentence:
       i = i.replace(key, value)
       newlist.append(i)
print newlist
```

Another way with map

```
word_list = { "hello" : "1"}

sentence= ['hello you, hows things', 'hello, good thanks']
newlist=[]

for key, value in word_list.items():
  newlist=map(lambda x: x.replace(key,value), sentence)
print newlist
```

Another way with a list comprehension

```
word_list = { "hello" : "1"}

sentence= ['hello you, hows things', 'hello, good thanks']
newlist=[]

for key, value in word_list.items():
  newlist=[x.replace(key,value) for x in sentence]
print newlist
```

note: updated for python3, thanks @MGM

Comment: Python 3 renamed `dict.iteritems() -> dict.items()`!

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.replace` is problematic, as a word could be a part of another word. Better use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with regular expression `\b\w+\b`, with `\b` being "word boundary", and use a callback function to get the replacement from the dictionary (or the word itself, if it is not in the dict).

```
>>> word_list = { "hello" : "1", "bye" : "2", 'you': "3"}
>>> sentence= ['hello you, hows things', 'you is not yourself', 'hello, good thanks']
>>> [re.sub(r'\b\w+\b', lambda m: word_list.get(m.group(), m.group()), s) for s in sentence]
['1 3, hows things', '3 is not yourself', '1, good thanks']
```

Also, not that by assigning to `i` within the loop, you are only changing the value bound to the variable `i`; you are *not* changing the string in the list! For this, you have to assign to the list element at that index, or use a list comprehension, as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code verbatim and it worked, but only prints the last "i". If you move the print into the for loop you get what you expected.

```
word_list = { "hello" : "1"}

sentence= ['hello you, hows things', 'hello, good thanks']

for key, value in word_list.iteritems():
    for i in sentence:
        i = i.replace(key, value)
        print i
```

output:

```
1 you, hows things
1, good thanks
```

Comment: Python 3 renamed `dict.iteritems() -> dict.items()`!

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
>>> word_list = { "hello" : "1", "bye" : "2"}
>>> sentence= ['hello you, hows things', 'hello, good thanks']
>>> [re.sub('|'.join(word_list.keys()), lambda x: word_list[x.group()], i) for i in sentence]
['1 you, hows things', '1, good thanks']
>>>
```

Comment: This, too, can replace words that are parts of other words. Better use `\b` for word boundaries.